# How to increase contrast in a 2D histogram by matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have to plot 2D histograms on several sets of data. I need to increase the contrast between points, as the differences are not well noticable.
Snice the maximum value in each dataset is different, I have to find an automatic way for normalization and increased intensity (contrast).

Here is the code I am using on each dataset:

```
H2, xedges, yedges, image = plt.hist2d(DF['x'], DF['y'], bins=(500, 500), cmap="hot", cbar = False, xticklabels = False, yticklabels = False, robust = True)
```

Probably, a solution is to:

1- Devide the hist numbers by the maximum of the dataset

2- Multiply the dataset by an intensity factor (such as 1000)

3- Plot the new data using seaborn.heatmap()

This can be achieved by:

```
D2H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(DF['x'], DF['y'], bins=(500, 500))
sns.heatmap(D2H/(D2H.max())*1000, cmap = "hot", cbar = False, xticklabels = False, yticklabels = False, robust = True)
```

Do you think this is the best method? I look forward to any better and simpler solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying by an arbitrary number will change the transformation of your `distribution`. I suggest you `normalise` the `histogram` using vmin/vmax, which can be found at the following link [Normalisation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html).

So `vmin = D2H.min(), vmax = D2H.max()`

Comment: Thanks. I already tried this method. The contrast is very poor in this method. BTW, multiplying does not change the transformation, since it is also devided by the max of the array (=normalized).

Comment: You could play around with your `colormap`. If you know the min-max values, you could set your colors to these values.

Comment: I'm assuming this but it has to be the `hot` `colormap`?

Comment: As I said, I have to plot on several datasets, and I do not want to check one by one what the max and min values are. It has to be automated. I found "hot" cmap better, but "inferno" and "magma" and some others were good as well.